# Installation using wceload and /noaskdest /noui

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am installing cab file of my application using wceload.exe. When my application already exists it gives message "My application is already installed.Reinstall?" How to avoid this message? Cab file installation launches when I use

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = @"\windows\wceload.exe";
info.Arguments = "\\My_Installer.cab";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

When I use

```
info.Arguments = "\\My_Installer.cab /silent";
```

or

```
info.Arguments = "/noaskdest /noui \\My_Installer.cab";
```

nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What platform are you working with? PocketPC?

Comment: Yes. I use PocketPC with Windows mobile CE. I use Datalogic Falcon X3 device. Also given code doesn't work in Visual Studio

Comment: Maybe I should uninstall application and after that to install it again? Does anybody know how to uninstall pocket PC program programmatically?

Comment: Please, can somebody help me?

Comment: At least I found the solution. It is necessary to uninstall application. After that to launch cab installer. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ab0d225-7db1-4a22-9163-b1c1a2a5832a/uninstall-using-configurationmanager?forum=windowsmobiledev

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete solution, if it will be necessary for somebody:

```
  ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
  System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
  Process proc = new Process();

  // uninstalls  application  
  doc.LoadXml("<wap-provisioningdoc>" +
              "<characteristic type=\"UnInstall\">" +
                        "<characteristic type=\"MyManufactuer  MyApplication\">"+
                          "<parm name=\"uninstall\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "</characteristic>" +
                      "</characteristic>" +
                  "</wap-provisioningdoc>");

  Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration(doc, false);

  // installs  application  
  info.FileName = @"\windows\wceload.exe";
  info.Arguments = @"\My_Installer.cab";

  // start the process
  proc.StartInfo = info;
  proc.Start();
  proc.WaitForExit();
```